# Understanding exec statement with a globals parameter

Tags: python

I have a python script that I'm picking up from someone else and am trying to understand what's happening when it runs.

I have a file in my current directory called __version__.py that contains the following line:

`__version__ = "1.0"`

In a separate script I have the following code:

```
import os

gdict = {}
curr_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
with open(os.path.join(curr_dir, "__version__.py")) as f:
    exec(f.read(), gdict)
```

I'm puzzled about what's going on with the exec statement.  My understanding from reading the documentation is that gdict is there to specify which global functions are available to the exec() function, and since it's empty there shouldn't be anything available to exec() beyond the built-in functions.  I had thought that gdict would remain empty, but when I run this code and then look at gdict.keys() I see:

```
dict_keys(['__builtins__', '__version__'])
```

I understand that the f.read() is creating a global variable called "__version__" with a value of "1.0", but how is gdict being populated?

Comment: The `__builtins__` key that gets added is precisely how the `exec`ed code gets access to the built-in functions, types, exceptions, etc.  If you didn't want that to happen, I believe you could pass a globals dictionary like `{ '__builtins__': {} }`.

Answer (score 0):

gdict from your program changes because python dictionaries are mutable. All available builtins will be added to the globals dict when you run exec(f.read(), gdict) and this is reflected when you view gdict.keys()